# Hover анимация линии

Tags: html, css

[image: hover effect]

Необходимо сделать анимацию подчеркивания:
линия при наведении будет увеличиваться влево и вправо

Comment: что нибудь пробовали ? например `:after {position: absolute}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'segoe ui', sans-serif;
}
ul>li{
    display: inline-block;
}
ul>li>a{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
ul>li>a:before,
ul>li>a:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    height: 3px;
    background: tomato;
    transition: .3s;
}
ul>li>a:before{
     left: 50%;    
}
ul>li>a:after{
    right: 50%;    
}
ul>li>a:hover:before,
ul>li>a:hover:after{    
    width: 50%;    
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Hover анимация линии</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('p').on({
    'mouseenter':function(){
        $('hr').stop().animate({'width': '50px'},500);
    },'mouseleave':function(){
        $('hr').stop().animate({'width': '10px'},500);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p align=center>Текст</p>
<hr style="width:10px" />
```

Jquery функция animate прекрасно справляется.